# Json python format extractor python

Tags: python, json

I am using openai, Requestesting json response, few times it works fine and few times it failed to load.

Is there any way I can convert unsaturated data to dict and below is example sting

```
{
    'finishReason': 'STOP',
    'response': '            {                "short_description": "some issue",                "detail_description": "",                "action_items": [                    {                        "action_name": "Raise ticket",                        "assignee": "NOC"                    },                    {                        "action_name": "Involve Java team oncall",                        "assignee": "NOC"                    },                    {                        "action_name": "Involve PKI team",                        "assignee": "NOC"                    }                ],                "followups": [                    "Check if issue is limited to xyz",                    "Check if issue M",                    "Check if issue is related to any latest changes in the configs"                ],                "issue_start_time": ISO 8601 string,                "urgency": 1,                "impact": 1,                "priority": 1            }'
}
```

I am trying below code

```
 json.loads(data["response"])
```

Error:

```
  Expecting value: line 1 column 1598 (char 1597)
```

Comment: It's a generation model, so the output is not always 100% valid, and you can't expect json.loads to load anything that's not inline with json formatting. The best you can do is to further improve your prompt to openai models and get better and more consistent result.

Comment: @chepner - there are singlequotes - everything under "response" is a string. I didn't see it for the first time either..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you manually format the `data` part, you'll see that there is unqouted string under *"issue_start_time"*:

```
{
    "short_description": "some issue",
    "detail_description": "",
    "action_items": [
        {
            "action_name": "Raise ticket",
            "assignee": "NOC"
        },
        {
            "action_name": "Involve Java team oncall",
            "assignee": "NOC"
        },
        {
            "action_name": "Involve PKI team",
            "assignee": "NOC"
        }
    ],
    "followups": [
        "Check if issue is limited to xyz",
        "Check if issue M",
        "Check if issue is related to any latest changes in the configs"
    ],
    "issue_start_time": ISO 8601 string,
    "urgency": 1,
    "impact": 1,
    "priority": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`yaml` parses the data string (already a dict) to a better formatted dict

```
import yaml

data = {
    'finishReason': 'STOP',
    'response': '            {                "short_description": "some issue",                "detail_description": "",                "action_items": [                    {                        "action_name": "Raise ticket",                        "assignee": "NOC"                    },                    {                        "action_name": "Involve Java team oncall",                        "assignee": "NOC"                    },                    {                        "action_name": "Involve PKI team",                        "assignee": "NOC"                    }                ],                "followups": [                    "Check if issue is limited to xyz",                    "Check if issue M",                    "Check if issue is related to any latest changes in the configs"                ],                "issue_start_time": ISO 8601 string,                "urgency": 1,                "impact": 1,                "priority": 1            }'
}

# Use yaml safe loader and convert response to dict
yaml.load(data["response"], Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
```